# Просмотр значения переменной функции через консоль

Tags: javascript, консоль

Нужно узнать значение переменной которая обьявлена в функции и недостижима в глобальном пространстве через консоль. Я не понимаю как запросить это значение в Google Chrome. Пробовал разобраться с точками остановки(breakpoints), говорит что переменная не обьявлена так же как и без них.

```
function check() {
    var variable = 100;
}
```

Просто запросить переменную `variable` нельзя, так как она обьявлена в функции.

Comment: стоит добавить пример кода

Comment: @Grundy готово.

Comment: пусть ваша функция возвращает значение этой переменной. В том месте, где вы её вызываете вы сможете присвоить её переменной и проверить её значение.

Comment: @Rafael Osipov я отлично знаю что в консоль можно вывести данные, но вопрос в отладке. У меня таких переменных может быть крайне много и они меняются в процессе продвижения по коду. Каждый раз открывать скрипт и добавлять console.log очень долго и неудобно, к тому же если выводить все что есть это просто будет захламлять консоль.

Comment: `Пробовал разобраться с точками остановки(breakpoints), говорит что переменная не обьявлена так же как и без них` - ну она объявлена.. только её значение вы сможете посмотреть только тогда, когда отладчик зайдет в функцию `check()` ...... через консоль посмотреть её нельзя никак

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский то есть что бы проверить ее нужно поставить брейкпоинт после обьявления переменной и запустить функцию? Или даже так нельзя проверить ее значение?

Comment: **только тогда, когда отладчик зайдет в функцию check()**  .......по сути да, после неё надо ставить бряк....точнее там должна быть хотя бы еще одна строка , хотя бы банально `var test;`, на которую бряк можно поставить...ибо на пустую строку его не поставить

Comment: Только хотел напомнить-сказать про волшебное слово **debugger;**, а смотрю - ответ уже есть. хых)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы создать точку остановки достаточно написать

```
debugger;
```

внутри вызываемой функции.
Далее открыть панель разработчика и посмотреть необходимые переменные.

Можно их вывести в консоль либо навести на имя переменной и увидеть текущее значение.

От текущего места можно исполнять код построчно.
Это самый удобный способ находить ошибки в сложных функциях.

Пример кода - 
http://take.ms/EL0Ox

Comment: Большое спасибо за информацию.